# One Environment for all mobile OSs

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I want to build an App that is going to be installed on Android, iOS. 
Is there a tool that allows me to build one app and to be compiled for both OSs

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can use "Unity 3D" to write the code once in C#, and then you can build separate apps for iOS, Android, Windows Phone, XBox, Playstations, Mac, PC. "Unity 3D" is free to download and install with PERSONAL license.  If you are an independent developer who does not make a lot of money, you can try it for free. But, if your company makes lots of money, then your company needs to buy a Pro licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [IntelXDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk). Which supports all mobile platforms.